# Can shared Random instance be used to get Gaussian distribution

Tags: java, random, gaussian

In java class there is random instance that is shared between two methods.

```
public class Utils{
    Random rand = new Random();

    public double nextGaussian1(){
          return rand.nextGaussian();
    }

    public double nextGaussian2(){
          return rand.nextGaussian();
    }   
}
```

Can I use only one Random instance to get Gaussian distributions from 2 methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use one instance of `Random`.  The backing implementation for `nextGaussian()` is Box, Muller, & Marsaglia's Polar method which generates Gaussians in pairs.  The first call to it will generate a pair and return the first of the two values, the next call will just return the previously generated second value.  The pairs are mathematically independent<sup>(*)</sup> if the uniform inputs are.  In theory this can be a problem if the uniforms come from a linear congruential generator with a bad lattice structure, but Java's LCG is pretty decent and in practice the results can be considered effectively independent for most uses.

The bigger question would be why do you need two different methods to be sources of Gaussians?  What does that gain you that just calling `rand.nextGaussian()` wouldn't achieve?

(*) - the Gaussian return values are sine & cosine components of a vector generated in polar coordinates, and are thus orthogonal.  For Gaussians, orthogonality implies independent.

Comment: I wrote this sample for simplicity. Actually, I use one utility method from several points of my program.  Every point of a program invokes random in utility method with different frequency. So I would like to understand, can I get normal distribution in every case or invocations from different places will affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

If the two methods are called randomly, this is fine, however if you call these in a pattern like follow, it won't work as intended as it generates pairs of Gaussian numbers

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    values1[i] = Utils.nextGaussian1();
    values2[i] = Utils.nextGaussian2();
}
```

This is the same problem as

```
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    values1[i] = rand.nextGaussian();
    values2[i] = rand.nextGaussian();
}
```

BTW A simple way to make a utility class is to use an `enum` with no instances

```
public enum Utils {;
     // class is final with a private constructor

     public static double nextGaussian() {
          return random.nextGaussian();
     }
}
```

Comment: Where I can read about why "pairs of Gaussian numbers" is not Gaussian numbers?
BTW It's simple but semantically not correct way to make utility class. Methods should be static. ;)

Comment: @skydreamerr You can read the code to see that every second value is altered to ensure a gaussian distribution.  I don't see a problem with using static methods on an `enum`.  What do you mean by "semantically not correct way" ?

Comment: Enum means enumeration. Enum is not intended to be utility class by language desiners. It looks like trick and it can confuse developers.

Comment: @skydreamerr The is the only way to directly say; this is a class with no instances. IMHO Other approaches are indirect and needlessly complicated.